# Change the default colorbar in xarray for non diverging data

Tags: python-xarray

xarrays plotting module is awesome because it detects automatically if the data is divergent or not and adjusts the colormap accordingly.

But what if I do not particularly like the default colormap choice for non-diverging data (matplotlibs [viridis](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html))?

Is there a simple way to change the default colormap in the xarray plotting module from viridis to lets say magma?

I would like to change this on all plots in a notebook without having to manually change the `cmap=...` kwarg on each plot.

Comment: This currently isn't supported, but a pull request to add an option for this would be welcome. Please raise an issue on the xarray github page to discuss: https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues

Answer (score 0):

Awesome. I openend an issue on [github](https://github.com/pydata/xarray/issues/2394).